# Setting the UITextView height to fit the content height in Objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have the code as below for my UITextView set up.

```
CGRect itemDescFrame = CGRectMake(20, 160, 280, 200);
UITextView *itemDesc = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:itemDescFrame];
...
itemDesc.editable = NO;
itemDesc.scrollEnabled = NO;
...
```

I have disabled the UITextView scroll bar, however some of the content on the bottom is being hidden. How can I set the UITextView height to fit to the content height?

Thanks

UPDATE:

```
NSLog(@"frame %@", itemDesc.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"content %@", itemDesc.contentSize.height);
```

Result:

```
2011-10-11 11:00:18.010 abc[1606:207] frame 200.000000
2011-10-11 11:00:18.010 abc[1606:207] content 200.000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a subclass of `UIScrollView`, `UITextView` has a property called `contentSize` which, in the case of a `UITextView`, should be the size that the text occupies after it is is placed in the view.  Try setting the height of the text view's frame to the height of `contentSize`.

Comment: I print out itemDesc.frame.size.height and itemDesc.contentSize.height, both are 200. Do you know why is it?

Comment: One reason might be that the values are the same until itemDesc is added as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this line of code to force the frame to update its size based on the height of the text it contains:

```
[self.myTextView sizeToFit];
```

Note that if you want to add additional padding you can set `textContainerInset`.

You'll want to call that when the text content changes and upon rotation. To make it easy to see the height adjust, set a background color on the `UITextView`.